# SharePoint documents only open in Client Application from within the Document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have spent countless hours but can't seem to figure it out. I have enabled

1. "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" under Site Collection Features and
2. "Open in the client application" under Advanced Settings in Library Settings for the Document Library

But it seems like it only open using the client application when I open documents while sitting inside the Document library, it always opens in the browser when I embed the link to the documents or insert it as a web part.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have just tried creating a hyperlink `<a href="/sites/Dev/Shared%20Documents/Test.xlsx">Test</a>` on a page in SharePoint online. It gives a dialog at the bottom of Internet Explorer asking to Open or Cancel. However it opens the document straight in excel client application when sitting in document library. In chrome, it always open in Excel Online because chrome doesn't know about `SharePoint.OpenDocuments` add-on. What web browser are you trying in?

Comment: We only use Chrome in the office, unfortunately.

Comment: I have this same issue, it happens in Chrome or IE when I test it.